# How can I get the extension entered by user in a Perl AGI script?

Tags: perl, asterisk, telephony, agi

I'm new to Asterisk AGI programming. Im trying to create a simple IVR, using [asterisk-perl](http://search.cpan.org/dist/asterisk-perl), where a user can enter any extension from 1 to 4. Here is my code so far:

```
use Asterisk::AGI;

$AGI = new Asterisk::AGI;

for($i = 0 ; $i < 2 ; $i++)
{
    $AGI->exec('Playback','welcome');

    $AGI->exec('WaitExten','5|m');


}
```

Now, I want to know the extension the user entered and take some action accordingly. How to get the extension entered by the user?

Thank You.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you want to use get_data, allowing you to play a file and then wait a given time for a given number of digits e.g.:

> $AGI->get_data('demo-welcome', 15000, 5);

See [here](http://kobesearch.cpan.org/htdocs/asterisk-perl/Asterisk/AGI.html#AGI_gt_get_data_filename_timeout_max)

Answer (score 0):

Well since the [WaitExten](http://voip-info.org/wiki-Asterisk+cmd+WaitExten) command changes the user to a new extension, I suppose you can read the special variable [${EXTEN}](http://www.voip-info.org/wiki/index.php?page=Asterisk+variables#PredefinedChannelVariables) after calling WaitExten. I'm not familiar with Asterisk::Perl though, I've only used FastAGI from Java, so I don't know the exact command, but there must be some command to read a variable's value.